# How can I make this plot awesome (colours by group plus alpha value by second group)

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I do have following dataframe:

[image: Dataframe to plot]

I plotted it the following way:

[image: Plot of the Dataframe]

Right now the plot looks ugly. Aside of using different font size, marker_edge_width, marker face color etc. I would like to have two colors for each protein (hum1 and hum2) and within the group the different pH values should have different intensities. What makes it more difficult is the fact that my groups do not have the same size.

Any ideas ?

P.S Such a build in feature would be really cool e.g colourby = level_one thenby level_two

Comment: Ok, i guess i have to make a RGBA color tuple and pass that to the plot funtcion

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
c1 = plt.cm.Greens(np.linspace(0.5, 1, 4))
c2 = plt.cm.Blues(np.linspace(0.5, 1, 4))
colors = np.vstack((c1,c2))
gr.unstack(level=(0,1))['conc_dil'].plot(marker='o',linestyle='-',color=colors,ax=ax)

plt.legend(loc=1,bbox_to_anchor = (0,0,1.5,1),numpoints=1)
```

gives:

[image]

P.S This post helped me:
[stacked bar plot and colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355832/pandas-stacked-bar-chart-duplicates-colors-for-large-legends)